# How to convert url to image to Image?

Tags: java, android

I get url to my Image, and want it make Image;
I want use this methods

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.digitalphotoartistry.com/rose1.jpg");
java.awt.Image image = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
```

or

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.digitalphotoartistry.com/rose1.jpg");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
```

but Android Studio can't find *ImageIO* and *java.awt.Toolkit*.  How can I add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `Bitmap` from url and then you can use that bitmap further to set image of an `ImageView`.

```
URL url = new URL("http://....");
Bitmap  image=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```